# Hangfire wrong date/time saved for ScheduleAt attribute

Tags: c#, multithreading, hangfire

I have a simple method where I try to schedule a task to run a single time at a specific hour.
Here is my function (lot of redundant code after testing all types of workarunds)

```
    public string Schedule(Guid id, JobType jobType, DateTime scheduleTime)
    {
        //DateTime is paresed from a format like this : "2020-05-19T20:50:00Z";
        return _backgroundJobClient.Schedule(() => task(), scheduleTime);
    }
```

If I run the above example with date : 2020-05-19T20:50:00Z in Hangfire.State.Data I have:

```
{"EnqueueAt":"2020-05-19T20:50:00.0000000Z",

"ScheduledAt":"2020-05-19T15:01:16.5174515Z"}
```

EnqueueAt is fine but ScheduledAt is behind with a few hours.
For database I am using Postgres and I have set also there the timezone right.

Has anybody some idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was confused with time parameter. There is no DateTime param for Schedule, you need to specify a delay for the task.

Hangfire schedule definition:

```
public static string Schedule([NotNull] this IBackgroundJobClient client, [InstantHandle][NotNull] Expression<Func<Task>> methodCall, TimeSpan delay);
```

Converting schedule date to TimeSpan worked for me:

```
private TimeSpan GetDelay(DateTime scheduled)
{
    return scheduled- DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: What will happen if the `scheduled.TimeOfDay` is 00:01:00, and the `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay` is 23:59:00?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias that's a nice catch, but I can't see how can I fix this. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Maybe `return scheduled - DateTime.Now;`?

Comment: Yep. I am new with C# Date API. Thanks for the feedback. I will update my answer.